# Efficient way: find row where nearly no zero appears in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem that as to be solved as efficient as possible. My current approach kind of works, but is extreme slow.

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, in this case I only care for one of them. It contains positive continuous numbers and some zeros.
**my goal:** is to find the row where nearly no zeros appear in the following rows.

To make clear what I mean I wrote this example to replicate my problem:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,3,4,0,4,0,5,1,0,1,2,3,4,
                   0,0,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,6,1,1,5,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,5,1,2,1,2,3,4],
                   index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=60, freq='15T'))
```

[image: Plotted data]
There are some zeros at the beginning, but they get less after some time.
Here comes my unoptimized code to visualize the number of zeros:

```
zerosum = 0 # counter for all zeros that have appeared so far
for i in range(len(df)):
    if(df[0][i]== 0.0):
        df.loc[df.index[i],'zerosum']=zerosum
        zerosum+=1
    else:
        df.loc[df.index[i],'zerosum']=zerosum
df['zerosum'].plot()
```

[image: Distribution of zeros]

With that unoptimized code I can see the distribution of zeros over time.

**My expected output:** would be in this example the date 01-Jan-2018 08:00, because no zeros appear after that date.

The problem I have when dealing with my real data is some single zeros can appear later. Therefore I can't just pick the last row that contains a zero. I have to somehow inspect the distribution of zeros and ignore later outliers.

Note: The visualization is not necessary to solve my problem, I just included it to explain my problem as good as possible. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer according to your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok

Second go

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
df = pd.DataFrame([0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,2,3,4,0,4,0,5,1,0,1,2,3,4,
                   0,0,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,6,1,1,5,1,2,3,4,4,4,3,5,1,2,1,2,3,4], 
                   index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=60, freq='15T'),
                   columns=['values'])
```

We create a column that contains the rank of each zero, and zero if there is a non-zero value

```
df['zero_idx'] = np.where(df['values']==0,np.cumsum(np.where(df['values']==0,1,0)), 0)
```

We can use this column to get the location of any zero of any rank. I dont know what your criteria is for naming a zero an outlier. But lets say we want to make sure at we are past at least 90% of all zeros...

```
# Total number of zeros
n_zeros = max(df['zero_idx'])
# Get past at least this percentage
tolerance = 0.9
# The rank of the abovementioned zero
rank_tolerance = math.ceil(tolerance * n_zeros)

df[df['zero_idx']==rank_tolerance].index
Out[44]: DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01 07:30:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='15T')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That solution would be good if no outliers would appear. Maybe I should have added that to my example.
The real data I'm dealing with is much longer and I sometimes get a single outlier zero.

Answer (score 0):

here my solution using a filter and [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 0, 5, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
                   0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 6, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4],
                  index=pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=60, freq='15T'))

a = df[0] == 0
df['zerosum'] = a.cumsum()

maxval = max(df['zerosum'])
firstdate = df[df['zerosum'] == maxval].index[1]
print(firstdate)
```

output:

```
 2018-01-01 08:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, If you need to get the index after the last zero occurred, you can try this:

```
last = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if(df[0][i] == 0):
        last = i
print(df.iloc[last+1])
```

or by Filtering:

```
new = df.loc[df[0]==0]
last = df.index.get_loc(new.index[-1])
print(df.iloc[last+1])
```